# how to send email terminal with "reply-to" or "from" option

Tags: macos, email, terminal

I know how to send an email with a terminal command in OS X :

```
mail -s "subject" receiver@domain.com
```

But I'm wondering how to set the reply-to or from option with this mail command in terminal.

Thank you for your help

Dam

Answer (score 1):

I assume you've already configured the mail delivery system on your OSX box so that it'll send mail off the machine.

You can affect the reply-to field by putting '~R account@domain.com' at the beginning of a line of the message body, or by setting the environment variable `REPLYTO`.

You can't change the 'from' address using `mail` unless you change the environment variables `USER` and `HOSTNAME`.  You may find better answers in the `postconf` or `sendmail` documentation.